# SVG doesn't display images I linked

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I generate an SVG image using Adobe Illustrator CS6. This image is located at my site media folder (root/sitemedia/images/). I put as a background of a jumbotron but it doesn't display anything, just a blank image.  When I openned in the browser (Safari, FF, Chrome) it displays the image that I want.

The css code I'm using is

```
.jumbotron{
         background: url(../images/jumbo-bg.svg) center no-repeat #FFF;
         background-size: cover;
}
```

The code generated by Illustrator is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="central" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="640px" height="480px" viewBox="0 0 640 480" enable-background="new 0 0 640 480" xml:space="preserve">
<image overflow="visible" width="640" height="480" id="image1" xlink:href="folder/image1.png"  transform="matrix(1.0002 0 0 1.0002 0 0)">
</image>
</svg>
```

I already changed the xlink:href of the image for the root folder but it doesn't work. What's happen with this image?

Comment: Does the `.jumbotron` have height/width because it's not shown in your code.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap the jumbotron has width: 100% by default. I can see the jumbotron and its content but its background is white

Comment: When you change the `background` path to the `.png` linked in the svg does it show up?

Comment: where is your css file relative to `root`?

Comment: @zgood it doesn't display anything. I'd tried putting ../sitemedia/images/folder/image1.png, /sitemedia/folder/images/image1.png  and /images/image1.png

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm using bootstrap the jumbotron has width: 100% by default. I can see the jumbotron and its content but its background is white

Comment: @jcuenod is im sitemedia/css/ folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you display an SVG file as a background-image (or any other image type such as an html `<img>` or SVG `<image>`) it must be complete within a single file to prevent privacy leaks.

Encode your png as a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) within the SVG document and it should work.

Comment: I have to do this. Thanks for the advice!